# To have different font for hint and text inside EditText in android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, android-edittext

Trying to have a light font for the hint and bold font for the text input entered by user in EditText. Is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
In resource file `strings.xml`

```
<string name="text"><b>Text input</b></string>
```

and then in your `layout.xml`, tag `<EditText>`

```
 <EditText android:text = "@string/text" />
```

Comment: I want to make hint text light

Comment: No way to set the `Typeface` different between `hint` et `text`, only this solution is applicable.

Another advice, please ask or talk in a polite way, if not no one wanna help you solve the problem